# Group nested field in mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document's structure in my MongoDB database:

```
[
  {
    name: "x1",
    stages: [
      {
        _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667054",
        type: "y1"
      },
      {
        _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667055",
        type: "y2"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "x2",
    stages: [
      {
        _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667054",
        type: "y1"
      },
      {
        _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667055",
        type: "y2"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  
]
```

I want to group inside each main document (those with `name` of `x1,x2,...`) the `stages` by their type (`y1,y2,...`) so basically nested group operation.

Here is the expected result I wish to get using the aggregation method:

```
[
  {
    name: "x1",
    stages: [
      {
        type: "y1",
        stages: [
          {
            _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667054",
            type: "y1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "y2",
        stages: [
          {
            _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2667055",
            type: "y2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
{
    name: "x2",
    stages: [
      {
        type: "y1",
        stages: [
          {
            _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2gggg667054",
            type: "y1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "y2",
        stages: [
          {
            _id: "60cb49c4977b0c64f2tttt667055",
            type: "y2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any help? I don't know how to continue on with my aggregation method (this snapshot code is the format I've succeeded to code a pre-code aggregation)

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Answer (score 1):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `stages` array
- `$group` by `_id` and stage `type` get first name field and construct the array of `stages`
- `$group` by only `_id` and get first name field and reconstruct the `stages` array with `type` field and `stages` sub array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$stages" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        type: "$stages.type"
      },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      stages: { $push: "$stages" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      stages: {
        $push: {
          type: "$_id.type",
          stages: "$stages"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QU8RLqS3eYW)